# How do I simplify this trig expression?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I simplify the expression of $\cos(2x+3x)\cos x+\sin(3x)\cos\left(\frac x2+x\right)$ ?

Comment: I've fixed tex, please check that I didn't modify anything.

Comment: Why did you write it as $2x+3x$ instead of $5x$?

Comment: @JoeL. is it possible to use (cos(2x)+cos(3x))⋅cosx ?? i calculated and found (for example,in degrees) cos(15)+cos(30) != cos(45) :(

Comment: A simple simplification is $\,\cos (2x+3x)=\cos 5x\,$...is there a typo here?

Comment: hat do you want to simplify it into?  It can be done cleanly into a function of $\cos(x/2)$ and $\sin(x/2)$.

Comment: @JoeL. : _How_ did you conclude that $\cos(2x+3x)\cos x$ is the same as $(\cos(2x)+\cos(3x))\cos x$ The two functions don't have the same period.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta & = \cos(\alpha+\beta) \\
\cos\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\alpha\sin\beta & = \cos(\alpha-\beta)
\end{align}
$$
Adding left sides and adding right sides gives
$$
2\cos\alpha\cos\beta = \cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)
$$
so
$$
\cos\alpha\cos\beta = \frac{\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{2}.
$$
A similar thing handles a product of a sine and a cosine.

**Later edit:** "Dr. Strangelove" doesn't seem to be getting excited about this answer, so I'll add a bit more.  The proposed identity includes $\cos(5x)\cos x$.  Let $5x$ be $\alpha$ and $x$ be $\beta$ in the identity above.  We get
$$
\cos(2x+3x)\cos x=\cos(5x)\cos x = \frac{\cos(5x+x) + \cos(5x-x)}{2} = \frac{\cos(6x)+\cos(4x)}{2}.
$$